# Conversion tracking for Mac App Store

Tags: facebook, ads, google-ads-api, mac-app-store

Google and Facebook offer SDK for conversion tracking on iOS (from online ads to app installs):

- Google: https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/
- Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads

However, I could not find equivalent SDKs for the Mac App Store.

Are there equivalent SDKs for the Mac AppStore?
If not, what's the best way to measure conversion rate for installs from the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach that most people use for this is to place a tracking pixel into their app.

On the first run of the app (note this is not the same as install as someone might install but never run the app), the tracking pixel fires and you can then just count the fires of that pixel.

Attribution (i.e. what caused that install) is difficult as usual - there are third parties who exist who can act as an intermediary that can do this, e.g. HasOffers or Kochava are two that spring to mind.

N.B. for Android installs from the Play Store, this "just works" with AdWords.

Answer (score 0):

At present Apple doesn't provide conversion tracking. [Later this year it will](http://readwrite.com/2014/06/04/apple-app-store-analytics-wwdc-2014). It's unclear to me how you think an SDK would be involved; it won't be.

Comment: Those SDK can be used for tracking conversion of Facebook/Google ads to iOS app installs. Apple announcement measure performance of the AppStore itself, not the ads that lead to it.

Comment: The Mac App Store also doesn't host advertisements so if "conversion rate for installs from the Mac App Store" doesn't mean conversion from looking at the listing to install the app then you probably need to explain more clearly, at least for one as dense as I.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else researching this (there are surprisingly few results for this topic on Google) you should focus on tracking conversions with [App Store](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-acquisition-marketing/) by Apple. Make sure to use UTMs to see which campaigns are performing.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge App Analytics by Apple are not available for the Mac apps. Only iOS and tvOS.